# Ugly yet simple proofs of the uniqueness of the empty set which do not facilitate understanding

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Take the proof that the empty set is unique.

Proof wiki has some nice proofs, especially the first is very easy to grasp and very intuitive once you accept that the empty set is always a subset. You can almost see how the first proof "creates" this fact.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Empty_Set_is_Unique

There are however ugly proofs of the same fact that just do not elucidate this fact as nicely, if at all.

Proof by contraposition:
Show that if $A$ and $B$ are empty sets, then $A=B$.

Assume $A \neq B$. Then either  $x \in A \land x \notin B$ or $x \in B \land x \notin A$. Therefore $A$ and $B$ are not both empty.

Proof by contradiction: Show that if $A$ and $B$ are empty sets, then $A=B$.

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are empty. Assume also that $A \neq B$. Then there is an $x$ such that either $x \in A \land x \notin B$ or $x \in B \land x \notin A$. This implies that $A$ or $B$ are not empty, which is a contradiction. Therefore $A=B$.

The mathematical facts here are very simple. And I think that the two ugly proofs provided by me are simpler than the beautiful one linked above, namely they work without knowledge that the empty set is a subset of all subsets. But I think we can all agree that the simple, ugly proofs do not facilitate an understanding as much. How is that possible? I have been told that simple proofs are better, always. I think that the relevant notion of simplicity  is not one of verbal brevity but one depending on the concepts used in the proof. Why then do these simpler proofs fail in terms of granting insight?

Comment: "I have been told simple proofs are better." Better is a meaningless, unmeasurable term, as is simpler. You have been told nonsense.  Sometimes simple proofs obscure, sometimes they hide.

Comment: However, there is an art to writing what is essentially the same proof so that it is simpler. For example, your simpler proof essentially proves a Lemma first, while the alternate proofs are essentially hiding the Lemma inside the proof. The Lemma clarifies by giving its own statement and proof. That is a very common way to simplify a proof.

Comment: The fact that there's only one empty set is pretty close to the axioms of set theory (it is a special case of the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), which your proofs invoke). Such fundamental  facts' reasons for being true might vary depending on technical decisions about foundational details, so the proofs don't give insight into "deep reasons" as much as they just demonstrate how the axioms work. The ideas of simplicity and elegance you're referring to might be more applicable to higher-level theorems.

Comment: In terms of demonstrating how the axioms work, your proofs are arguably more enlightening. Can you tell where the proofwiki proof uses extensionality?

Comment: The "definition of set equality", $\forall A,B. (A \subseteq B \wedge B \subseteq A) \leftrightarrow A = B$, referred to in the first proofwiki prood, *is* a atatement of the axiom of extensionality, "two sets that have exactly the same elements are equal". The definition of the subset relation is just $(A \subseteq B) \leftrightarrow (\forall x. x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$.

Comment: If we're comparing different ways of proving such a basic fact, it seems unfair to view these various ways of formulating extensionality as identical. Sure, it's the same informal principle no matter how you write it, but in that sense all the proposed proofs are the same informal argument too. Verifying the equivalence of the axiom statements is as hard as verifying the proposed proofs.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think the quoted proof is simpler than either of your two proposed alternatives. You don't have to refer to the lemma that the empty set is a subset of every set. Just use the definition of equality: two sets $A,B$ are equal if $\forall x (x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B)$ and $\forall x (x\in B\Rightarrow x\in A)$. Both these sentences are vacuously true when $A$ and $B$ are both empty.

Comment: That could serve as the definition of equality, but is it actually? This sort of illustrates what I said in my comment: the proofs of obvious, fundamental facts are just artifacts of technical foundational choices.

Comment: @Karl: it's the axiom of foundation / extensionality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) which, yes, is a specific technical foundational choice.

Comment: I guess my point is that the minor differences among all these proofs are more related to how one chooses to state the underlying axiom (everyone has stated it a little differently here!) than to any other aesthetic or organizational choices about how to present a logical argument, because basically no argument is needed. That makes this theorem a questionable one for studying proof beauty and informativeness.

Comment: @karl I take your point, but I was working within the relatively standard framework that sets are determined by their elements. (i.e. two sets are the same iff they have the same elements) Moreover I was trying to work within the same framework of the OP. Both of the OP's suggested alternative proofs are based on this same principle.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it:

When you say "$A$ is empty", you're specifying exactly which elements are in $A$ (namely, none). If you say the same thing about $B$, then $A$ and $B$ have exactly the same elements. So by [extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), they're equal.

All the proofs discussed on this post are different ways of formalizing the same basic idea above, but they differ in how the extensionality axiom is expressed. As a result, it's an apples-to-oranges comparison: the different formal proofs aren't really doing the same work, because they're starting from different formal premises. These premises are equivalent, but verifying this equivalence is harder than verifying the simple proofs themselves, so if you declared one expression of the axiom to be the "right one", you'd be favoring one of the proofs and forcing the others to become somewhat more complicated.

For this reason, a theorem that at a high level is simply a direct consequence of an axiom is probably not a good place to look for proof beauty and informativeness. The proofs aren't giving us different insights about empty sets, they're just demonstrating the utility of stating the axiom in slightly different ways.